# How can i find the tag at which my cursor points in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing

I want to know whether we can find a tag in JEditorPane in java swing where my cursor is pointing..
For ex.
following is the text content in my editor pane..

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div><!--Cursor inside the div tag--></div>
</body>
</html>
```

for instance suppose this is the text inside my editor pane. and my cursor is inside the  tag. now what i want is a function that returns me the tag in which the cursor is. Is it possible?

Here cursor is in `<div>` tag so function should return `"div"` or `"<div>"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `DIV` is defined in [`HTML.Tag`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTML.Tag.html), so you can iterate though the elements of your [`HTMLDocument`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html) in a [`CaretListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/CaretListener.html). You can get the offsets from the attribute's child element.

Answer (score 0):

HTMLDocument doc=(HTMLDocument)pane.getDocument();
Element elem=doc.getCharacterElement(pane.getCaretPositon());
The take a look at the elem's attributes or elem.getParent() attributes because the char elem is text but the div is parent element's attribute.